# Why outer measure?

Tags: measure-theory

In constructing the Lebesgue measure we start by defining the outer measure of a set in terms of coverings of the set by countable collection of cubes.

Suppose we instead start by approximating sets from the inside. Say, by defining the "inside measure" of a set as the supremum of the total volume of any countable collection of disjoint cubes contained in the set.

I can see that we would run into problems. For example on $[0,1]$ the set of rationals and set of irrationals would both have "inside measure" $0$ whereas the interval as a whole would have "inside measure" $1$.

What I would like to have is an intuitive understanding of why we run into these problems when approximating from inside whereas approximating from outside gives us a measure theory which works.

The reason I am asking is that for simple sets, for eg. when calculating the area of a circle, approximating from outside and approximating from inside works equally well.

Comment: Because Carathéodory's theorem.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Indeed. But I am looking for intuition on why one cannot have a Carathéodory-like theorem for "inside measure".

Comment: There is a notion of inner measure, but it's not the one that you suggest. The inner measure of the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ is $1$, and not $0$. You're talking about "the measure of the interior" (the irrationals indeed have an empty interior).

Comment: Well, if we use disjoint cubes, the definition is certainly not symmetric with the usual construction in terms of outer measure where no disjointness is needed. If we give up on it, inner measure will almost always be infinite.

Comment: The class of "simple sets" for which your "inner" construction works is actually known under the name "Jordan measurable sets", and they are precisely the ones whose boundary has measure zero.

Comment: @AlexanderShamov Isn't Jordan measurability defined in terms of finite collections of rectangles. I was wondering about what happens if we approximate from the inside but allow countable collections?

Comment: The distinction "finite vs. countable" only matters if we approximate from outside. For approximations from inside the $\sup$ over finite collections equals the $\sup$ over countable ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you approximate from outside you get an outer measure that is *subadditive*: $\mu^\ast[A \cup B] \le \mu^\ast[A] + \mu^\ast[B]$. This allows to think of measure as some kind of a "norm" of a set, and, in particular, define a metric $\rho(A,B) := \mu^\ast[A \vartriangle B]$, where $\vartriangle$ is symmetric difference. Completion and extension by continuity using this metric gives you measure theory (by this I mean that, first of all, the measure algebra is just the completion of the space of "simple" sets by this metric, and measurable sets are exactly those that can be approximated by "simple" ones using this metric).

Now if you try to approximate from inside, you get an inequality in the wrong direction: for $A$ and $B$ disjoint $\mu[A \cup B] \ge \mu[A] + \mu[B]$. So there is no metric, no completion, ..., no measure theory. In particular, this doesn't give any straightforward way to select which sets are measurable and map them to elements of the measure algebra.

Comment: It is not clear to me why the inequality would be reversed. If I have a disjoint collection of "simple" sets contained in $A \cup B$ then I can break it up into two collections, one contained in $A$ and one contained in $B$. If the measure of a set is defined as the supremum of the sum of measures of disjoint simple collections, won't I again have $\mu[A \cup B] \leq \mu[A] + \mu[B]$.

Comment: There might be sets in $A \cup B$ that are not contained in $A$ or $B$. So generally there are better ways to approximate $A\ cup B$ than to approximate each of them separately. Depending on whether we approximate from above or from below, this "better" turns into two different inequalities.